# How come I cannot run satchmo_check?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I'm stuck on step 1 of test and install the data here: http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/settings.html

When I try to run the command, I get the following error:

```
(pyweb27)user@mint ~/Documents/workspace/python/site $ python manage.py satchmo_check
Unknown command: 'satchmo_check'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I do have satchmo installed:

```
(pyweb27)user@mint ~/Documents/workspace/python/site $ python
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django; import satchmo_store;
>>> satchmo_store.get_version()
'0.9.3-pre hg-2553:76b7dccafc76'
```

Am I doing something wrong? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is satchmo included in the `INSTALLED_APPS` var in your settings? Could you perhaps run `python manage.py help` and see if satchmo is mentioned in there?

Comment: I copied the settings according to the documentation.  I ran help and noticed that my previously working commands are no longer on the list (the ones for south). I also have south in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Ok, so I noticed that now my `settings.py` is no longer being detected. I changed around my project structure to match that of the example in the Satchmo documentation.  I'm not sure how I can get it to be detected now.. I do have a `__init__.py` in the folder already.

Comment: I created a new project and copied over all my files as is and the issue no longer occurs...